# What the difference between google.protobuf.Any and google.protobuf.Value?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I want th serialize int/int64/double/float/uint32/uint64 into protobuf, which one should I use ? which one is more effective ?

For example :

```
message Test {
    google.protobuf.Any   any   = 1;   // solution 1
    google.protobuf.Value value = 2;   // solution 2
};

message Test {                         // solution 3
   oneof Data {
        uint32   int_value    = 1;
        double   double_value = 2;
        bytes    string_value = 3;
        ...
   };
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, you'd better use `oneof`.

You can not pack from or unpack to a built-in type, e.g. double, int32, int64, to `google.protobuf.Any`. Instead, you can only pack from or unpack to a message, i.e. a class derived from `google::protobuf::Message`.

`google.protobuf.Value`, in fact, is a wrapper on `oneof`:

```
message Value {
  // The kind of value.
  oneof kind {
    // Represents a null value.
    NullValue null_value = 1;
    // Represents a double value.
    double number_value = 2;
    // Represents a string value.
    string string_value = 3;
    // Represents a boolean value.
    bool bool_value = 4;
    // Represents a structured value.
    Struct struct_value = 5;
    // Represents a repeated `Value`.
    ListValue list_value = 6;
  }
}
```

Also from the definition of `google.protobuf.Value`, you can see, that there's no int32, int64, or unint64 fields, but only a `double` field. IMHO (correct me, if I'm wrong), you might lose precision if the the integer is very large. Normally, `google.protobuf.Value` is used with `google.protobuf.Struct`. Check *google/protobuf/struct.proto* for detail.